# Install Service Worker on apex.oracle.com

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Can I have some help installing a Service Worker on an application stored on the server apex.oracle.com.

Im currently installing the server worker with this code running on page load:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js', {
    scope : './'
  }).then(function (registration) {
    var serviceWorker;
    if (registration.installing) {
      serviceWorker = registration.installing;
      printState('installing');
    } else if (registration.waiting) {
      serviceWorker = registration.waiting;
      printState('waiting');
    } else if (registration.active) {
      serviceWorker = registration.active;
      printState('active');
    }
    if (serviceWorker) {
      printState(serviceWorker.state);
      serviceWorker.addEventListener('statechange', function (e) {
        printState(e.target.state);
      });
    }
  }).catch (function (error) {
    printState(error);
  });
}
```

And i get the errors:

```
A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
/pls/apex/apex//mvx/r/72250/files/static/v5/sw.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE
```

I have to get this application with service worker because i need it to run offline.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Changed the lines:

```
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js', {
    scope : './'
```

to

```
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#sw.js', {
    scope : './#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#'
```

And it worked.

Comment: You should rather create an answer to your question than only editing it..

Comment: I did the same thing and I still get the error. Could you please give me more info about how to add the service worker?

Comment: @ApostolisI. How is your serviceworker.js file?

Comment: @goemic First post here. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Marvin it is an empty file. I am trying to do add the "add app to homescreen" popup like this url: https://blog.betapage.co/how-to-add-add-to-homescreen-popup-in-web-app-99d5237fabff